# Can't keep faces message after navigation from preRender

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

in my preRender code for a page i add faces message then make navigation to another page as follows:

```
if(error){
addMessageToComponent(null,"AN ERROR HAS OCCURRED");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash()
                .setKeepMessages(true);
navigateActionListener("myoutcome");
}
```

and the util methods for adding message and navigation are:

```
public static String getClientId(String componentId)
    {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();

        UIComponent c = findComponent(root, componentId);
        return c.getClientId(context);
    }

    public static UIComponent findComponent(UIComponent c, String id)
    {
        if (id.equals(c.getId())) { return c; }
        Iterator<UIComponent> kids = c.getFacetsAndChildren();
        while (kids.hasNext())
        {
            UIComponent found = findComponent(kids.next(), id);
            if (found != null) { return found; }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param componentId
     *            : the id for the jsf/primefaces component without formId:
     *            prefix. <br>
     *            if you use null then the message will be added to the
     *            h:messages component.
     **/
    public static void addMessageToComponent(String componentId, String message)
    {

        if (componentId != null)
            componentId = GeneralUtils.getClientId(componentId);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(componentId,
                new FacesMessage(message));
    }

public static void navigateActionListener(String outcome)
    {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        NavigationHandler navigator = context.getApplication()
                .getNavigationHandler();
        navigator.handleNavigation(context, null, outcome);
    }
```

but messages are not saved and so it doesn't appear after redirect.

please advise how to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `preRenderView` event runs in the very beginning of the `RENDER_RESPONSE` phase. It's **too late** to instruct the `Flash` scope to keep the messages. You can do this at the latest during the `INVOKE_APPLICATION` phase.

Since there's no standard JSF component system event for this, you'd need to homebrew one:

```
@NamedEvent(shortName="postInvokeAction")
public class PostInvokeActionEvent extends ComponentSystemEvent {

    public PostInvokeActionEvent(UIComponent component) {
        super(component);
    }

}
```

To publish this, you need a `PhaseListener`:

```
public class PostInvokeActionListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.getApplication().publishEvent(context, PostInvokeActionEvent.class, context.getViewRoot());
    }

}
```

After registering it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.example.PostInvokeActionListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

You'll be able to use the new event as follows:

```
<f:event type="postInvokeAction" listener="#{bean.init}" />
```

You only need to make sure that you've at least a `<f:viewParam>`, otherwise JSF won't enter the invoked phase at all.

The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) already supports this event and the `preInvokeAction` event out the box. See also [the showcase page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/InvokeActionEventListener) which also demonstrates setting a facesmessage for redirect.

Comment: the postInvokeAction will be equivalent to preRenderView event ?

Comment: what i want to accomplish is when user making get request for the page, make a check and if it fails then add error message then navigate to another page, so i am doing this logic in preRenderView. will this new event make the same behavior ?

Comment: They are not the same. The `postInvokeAction` runs in the end of invoke action phase, which is perfectly on time to set messages in flash scope. The `preRenderView` runs in the beginning of render response phase, which is too late to set messages in flash scope. That's the whole point of this answer.

Comment: i am lost here.can i perform my check in this event ? does it run before rendering the page ?

Comment: I don't understand you either. You just need to replace `<f:event type="preRenderView">` by `<f:event type="postInvokeAction">` after having added the abovementioned code to your environment (or having placed OmniFaces JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib`) and if necessary add a dummy `<f:viewParam>` if you don't have any one. The showcase page contains a demo.

Comment: ,what i want to accomplish is when user making get request for the page, make a check and if it fails then add error message then navigate to another page, so i am doing this logic in preRenderView and user gets redirected but the message doesn't appear, you got what i am trying to day ?

Comment: Yes, I have explained the cause and answered the solution. What's unclear to the answer?