# JSF FlashScope not working on FacesContext redirect

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem with JSF's FlashScope, note that I'm aware that the redirect should point to the same base path as the calling page.

My case, the action will be initialized when a client click a link from his/her email, then it will load a .xhtml (has a preRenderView event) page with a backing bean to check the parameters passed. When the parameters are wrong it must redirect to a new page with message.

The View:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="dummy" />
        <f:event listener="#{signupMaterialBean.initFromContext()}"
            type="preRenderView"></f:event>
    </f:metadata>

    <h:outputText value="#{signupMaterialBean.html}" escape="false"></h:outputText>

</ui:composition>
```

The Backing Bean:

```
public void initFromContext() {
    try {
        Map<String, String> params = facesContext.getExternalContext()
                .getRequestParameterMap();
        ...
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {      
        try {
            Message message = new Message();
            String msg = "Invalid parameters";
            message.setMessage(msg);

            JSFUtils.flashScope().put("message", message);

            facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("message.xhtml");
            facesContext.responseComplete();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

The redirect works, but the message save in FlashScope is gone. Any idea why the flash scope is being deleted or another way to do it?

message.xhtml

```
    <ui:define name="head"></ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <div class="box-middle-content faded">
            <div class="message">
                <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{flash.message.message}"></h:outputText>
                <br />
                <p>
                    <h:outputText value="#{msgs['message.footer']}" escape="false" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

JSFUtils

```
public class JSFUtils {
    public static Flash flashScope() {
        return (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getFlash());
    }
}
```

Updated view:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="dummy"></f:viewParam>
        <f:event type="postInvokeAction"
            listener="#{signupMaterialBean.initFromContext}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <h:outputText value="#{signupMaterialBean.html}" escape="false"></h:outputText>

</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<f:event type="preRenderView">` is too late to set a flash scoped attribute. The flash scope can't be created when JSF is currently sitting in render response phase. You basically need to set the flash scoped attribute *before* render response phase. In spite of the name `preRenderView`, this event is actually fired *during* (the very beginning of) the render response phase.

You'd basically need to invoke the listener method during INVOKE_ACTION phase. As there's no standard `<f:event>` type for this, you'd need to homegrow one. This is outlined in detail in this answer: [Can't keep faces message after navigation from preRender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144611/cant-keep-faces-message-after-navigation-from-prerender/13144845#13144845).

You'd ultimately like to end up as:

```
<f:event listener="#{signupMaterialBean.initFromContext()}"
         type="postInvokeAction" />
```

Note that this event is already provided by [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org). See also [the `InvokeActionEventListener` showcase page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/InvokeActionEventListener) which handles exactly this issue.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the catch on `NullPointerException` is a huge code smell. Don't catch runtime exceptions like that. Prevent them by performing nullchecking as `if (foo != null)` and so on. Also those empty catches on `IOException` are very bad. Remove them all and just add `throws IOException` to the method.

Further, the redirect path problem is fixed since Mojarra 2.1.14. So since that version you could safely redirect to a different base path.

Comment: Again thank you very much Balus, you're always of great help :-) I'll try omnifaces and give update. I'll take your notes on the Exceptions and will give Mojarra 2.1.14 a try.

Comment: Initial feedback, I've added omnifaces and was able to successfully invoke postInvokeAction with the changes specified but I still have the flash message not showing. I'll add the JSFUtils and messages.xhtml page I'm calling in the original post for reference.

Comment: I've found my problem it seems omnifaces's Faces.redirect("message.xhtml"); is not saving the FlashScope data, so instead I used: facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("message.xhtml"); facesContext.responseComplete();.

Comment: The `Faces#redirect()` prepends by default the context path when a relative URL is given, so you might have ended up in a different folder. The `responseComplete()` call is unnecessary, the `ExternalContext#redirect()` is already doing that.